# Two cookies with the same name but slightly different domain name? How do i access them with JS

Tags: javascript, cookies, path

So there are two cookies, one under "www.mywebsite.com" and the other under "mywebsite.com" so after some testing i managed to figure out the latter is for logins to my site and the former is just like, whenever anyone visits the site I think (or something along those lines, I don't know the specifics.

At any rate, they are both named xxxx, and when I try to access them I am given the one from www.mywebsite.com and I need the other one, how can I change which cookie is accessed in javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the cookie is written to a specific subdomain, then that cookie can only be accessed by that particular subdomain.

Cookies set for `.mywebsite.com` can be accessible at `www.mywebsite.com`, but not vice versa.

Comment: thank you for this answer, so basically i can't access the cookie I want unless I'm on that subdomain?

Comment: @Gabriel Correct, but if you are in control of this website, why not just write the cookie to `.mywebsite.com` so the cookie is accessible? You can specify the `domain` when you are writing a cookie.

Comment: How do you get access to the top level domain cookie, from the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

since `www` is a subdomain you need to be on that subdomain to access that cookie. So it seems your cookies as subdomain based.

if you want the non-subdomain one you need to move your document location to mywebsite.com without that subdomain.

and you'll better use global cookies next time and make their names unique